# Server validation in other domain

Tags: java

I need a solution to a general problem that i have.

I have a site with domain called `foo.com` and a cross domain called `foo_goo.com`

In `foo.com` there is a `form` with several fields: userName, firstName, lastName, email...

When the user press the **submit** button (in the form) i need to make a server validation on this fields, the server who make the validation is in the cross domain (`foo_goo.com`).

Any solution to this problem? (ajax, json, servlet...)

What is the prefer why to do it?

Comment: I don't understand your problem.. just change the action of your form to a .php script on your cross domain? `<form method="POST" action="http://foo_goo.com/validation.php">`

Comment: I have 2 servers, in the first server i have the form, in the second server i the validations. They need to communicate with each other. When the user press the submit button, the second server needs to send a response if all the validation passes. If not, he need to send an appropriate message that tell to the first server that their is a problem with one or more validation. And then the first server (with the form) need to show an appropriate message to the user. How can they communicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you a php, proxy, but there are other solutions like JSONP or a feature in HTML5 that might help you: [Cross Domain Solutions Full client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551363/lets-solve-cross-domain-ajax-totally-on-the-client-using-script-tags)

Main Options I found interesting:

- JSONP
- PHP Proxy
- HTML5 window.postMessage